# Quaternion angleTo not distinguishing between left and right angle

Tags: javascript, three.js, quaternions

Sorry for hard to get title, topic is not trivial.

I am writing a carousel for images in three.js

See picture_related:

[image: chain carousel]

[ move to TL;DR at the end if you are bored already ]

The images ( aka planes ) are added to a group in a circular alignment with this function:

```
function createObjects(){

let angleLambda = 360 / 6;

for (let c = 1; c < 7; c++) {
    let geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1.5);
    let texture1 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("pic/0" + c + ".jpg");
    let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture1, side: THREE.DoubleSide});

    let plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    plane.rotation.y = -THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(angleLambda * (c-1));  //negative number for clockwise alignment
    plane.translateZ(3.5);

    carousel.add(plane);
}
}
```

In this case, 6 images (thus magic numbers). Spawn plane, rotate, translate, add to group.

Now I want to rotate the carousel to a specific image and then stop. As a workaround I managed to solve the problem already with

```
    if(carousel.rotation.y <= THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(360/6*5)){
    carousel.rotation.y += 0.01;
    }
```

in the animate function.

But I'm really unhappy with it. What I **REALLY** want is a solution in the likes of this:

```
    if(carousel.rotation.y <= carousel.children[4].quaternion.angleTo(camera.quaternion))
    {
    carousel.rotation.y += 0.01;
    }
```

This *kind of* works up to a point. It finds the correct angle up to image 3 and stops there. But as soon as I wanna rotate to, let's say, image 5, it will stop at image 2. Like the polar opposite of the image I'm aiming at. I think I'm having a clue to why this happens, namely the angle for the image on the left side is the same as the image on the right side in that the angle towards the camera is equally high and I'm getting the positive number for both which is equal.

I just can't wrap my head around this. How can I distinguish between the two angles for the images? Am I expected to write a big state machine where I remember all the positions and double check each time I want to spin the carousel?

TL;DR

How can I know the correct radians / angle for images on the left side of the imagewheel in [pic_related]? AngleTo ( camera ) will obviously return the same numbers for left and right side images. How to do it "correctly"?

Bonus:

It kind of feels weird to add 0.01 to object rotation, checking each update whether I already reached target_rotation. Is there something like object.rotateUntil(x) or object.rotate(45°) that just gives me a smooth transition into the new state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it relatively elegant. Let me post the whole code and then just explain a thing or two. Also the code was sligthly modified to increase logic and efficiency.

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );

renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
camera.position.z = 5;

let carousel = new THREE.Group();
carousel.position.set(0,0,0);

let numberPics = 6
let debugFlag = true;

function initialize(){
    createObjects();
    addObjectsToScene();
    animate();
}


function createObjects(){

    let angleLambda = 360 / numberPics;

    for (let c = 0; c < numberPics; c++) {
        let geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1.5);
        let texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("pic/0" + c + ".jpg");
        let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture, side: THREE.DoubleSide});

        let plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        plane.rotation.y = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(angleLambda * (c));
        plane.translateZ(3.5);

        carousel.add(plane);
    }
}

function addObjectsToScene(){

    scene.add(carousel);
}

function getRotaryAngleFor(targetPlane){

    let targetRotation = [];

    if(targetPlane > numberPics){
        return;
    }
    targetRotation["angle"] = carousel.children[targetPlane].quaternion.angleTo(camera.quaternion);

    //console.log(THREE.MathUtils.radToDeg(targetRotation["angle"]));
    //console.log(THREE.MathUtils.radToDeg(carousel.children[targetPlane].rotation.y));
    //console.log(THREE.MathUtils.radToDeg(carousel.children[targetPlane].rotation.y + targetRotation["angle"]));

    targetRotation["direction"] = "right";
    if(carousel.children[targetPlane].rotation.y + targetRotation["angle"] === THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(360)){
        targetRotation["direction"] = "left";
    }
    return targetRotation;

}

function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    if(debugFlag){
        let deltaRot = getRotaryAngleFor(5);

     /*   if(deltaRot["direction"] === "left"){
            carousel.rotateY( -deltaRot["angle"]);
        }
        else{
            carousel.rotateY( deltaRot["angle"]);
        }*/

        //shortened to:
        carousel.rotateY( deltaRot["direction"] === "right" ? deltaRot["angle"] : -deltaRot["angle"]);

        debugFlag ^= true;
    }

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

initialize();
```

One big refactoring is the createObjects function which now starts at 00.jpg and adds the images in a normal way to the carousel instead of counterclockwise. I did this initially because my head wanted the images to align to the left which turned out to be a rather hindrance.

Now the main logic for this problem is in this function:

```
function getRotaryAngleFor(targetPlane){

    let targetRotation = [];

    if(targetPlane > numberPics){
        return;
    }
    targetRotation["angle"] = carousel.children[targetPlane].quaternion.angleTo(camera.quaternion);

    //console.log(THREE.MathUtils.radToDeg(targetRotation["angle"]));
    //console.log(THREE.MathUtils.radToDeg(carousel.children[targetPlane].rotation.y));
    //console.log(THREE.MathUtils.radToDeg(carousel.children[targetPlane].rotation.y + targetRotation["angle"]));

    targetRotation["direction"] = "right";
    if(carousel.children[targetPlane].rotation.y + targetRotation["angle"] === THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(360)){
        targetRotation["direction"] = "left";
    }
    return targetRotation;

}
```

I left the debug console prints inside so you could easily check the values if you liked.

So basically what I did here is to add the angle between the plane and camera (aka the  [...]quaternion.angleTo(camera.quaternion) part) to the rotation of the plane (which can be gotten without problems). If the sum of this addition equals 360° , we found the image on the right side (in relation to our camera).

Since I refactored the function which adds the images to the carousel, all that's left to do really is just to rotate the carousel by the degrees we calculated. You can easily go on and animate this by adding rotation in the factor 0.01, but I decided to just flip the carousel to the targetPlane for demonstration purpose here:

```
    function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    if(debugFlag){
        let deltaRot = getRotaryAngleFor(5);

     /*   if(deltaRot["direction"] === "left"){
            carousel.rotateY( -deltaRot["angle"]);
        }
        else{
            carousel.rotateY( deltaRot["angle"]);
        }*/

        //shortened to:
        carousel.rotateY( deltaRot["direction"] === "right" ? deltaRot["angle"] : -deltaRot["angle"]);

        debugFlag ^= true;
    }

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```